# Hide and show specific divs on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay i have dynamic categories that i select from data base ,i put them in a select drop down,
and each categorie has multi articles,
first of all i display all articles
the problem is,i want to on select a categorie,i only display articles related to that categorie and hide the rest,
for that i put the articles in divs ,and each div it has it own related categorie class.
im stuck how to hide and display them tho 
here is my code for example:

```
 <select  id="selectleft" >
     <option value="categorie">categorie</option></center>
         <option value="categorie1">sport</option>
         <option value="categorie2">movies</option>
         <option value="categorie3">news</option>


        </select>
```

and the articles are displayed like this

```
<div class="categorie1>article 1 </div>
<div class="categorie1>article 2 </div>
<div class="categorie2>article 1 </div>
<div class="categorie2>article 2 </div
<div class="categorie3>article 3 </div>
<div class="categorie3>article 3 </div
```

okay i want  for example if i select categorie1 ,all divs with class categorie 1 get  showe and rest get hidden

Comment: have a look at change handler and class selector

Comment: i cant find out what to try..i know about hide() and show() but how do i use that to acomplish what i want?

Comment: please be clear about what you want, in first paragraph you said **the problem is,i want to on select a categorie,i only display articles related to that categorie and hide the rest**

and in last line you said

**if i select categorie1 ,all divs with class categorie 1 get hidden**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help ;)

```js
$('#selectleft').change(function() {
  /* hide visible articles */
  $('.category:visible').hide();
  
  /* show selected option articles */
  $('.' + this.value).show();
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="selectleft">
      <option value="categorie">categorie</option>
      <option value="categorie1">sport</option>
      <option value="categorie2">movies</option>
      <option value="categorie3">news</option>
    </select>

    <div class="category categorie">article(categorie option 1 default selected)</div>
    <div class="category categorie1">article 1(sport option 2)</div>
    <div class="category categorie1">article 2(sport option 2)</div>
    <div class="category categorie2">article 1(movies option 3)</div>
    <div class="category categorie2">article 2(movies option 3)</div>
    <div class="category categorie3">article 3(news option 4)</div>
    <div class="category categorie3">article 3(news option 4)</div>
```

Comment: hi,i dont want to put new question,i would really like if you help me more,so what  i want next, is when i click on categorie i view the full articles but...if like two articles have same name,i only  show the first for example if i click on categorie in your example it should show article 1,article 2,article 3 ,and others hide them cuz they have same names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change()` event handler

```js
$('#selectleft').change(function() {
  // hide all div
  $('.categorie').hide();
  // or hide only the rest by
  // $('.categorie').not('.' + this.value).hide();

  // show div based on selected option
  $('.' + this.value).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectleft">
  <option value="categorie">categorie</option>
  <option value="categorie1">sport</option>
  <option value="categorie2">movies</option>
  <option value="categorie3">news</option>
</select>

<div class="categorie categorie1">article 1</div>
<div class="categorie categorie1">article 2</div>
<div class="categorie categorie2">article 1</div>
<div class="categorie categorie2">article 2</div>
<div class="categorie categorie3">article 3</div>
<div class="categorie categorie3">article 3</div>
```

Comment: its close,but that doin the oposite that i want,it shows the divs that i dont select

Comment: how to edit it to make it show the articles of categorie i select,and hide the rest divs?

Comment: yes but i want the articles visible on load ...then i start hidden the rest i dont select,or i have to hide them on load?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106776/discussion-between-mounir-federere-and-pranav-c-balan).

Answer (score 0):

> **According to what you have told, I made the code. please check the following snippet.**

```js
$('#selectleft').change(function()
{
  $('.article').addClass('deactive');
   var x = $('#selectleft').val();
   $('.'+x).removeClass('deactive');
});
```

```css
.deactive{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> select cotegories</h1>
<select  id="selectleft" >
     <option value="categorie">categorie</option>
         <option value="categorie1">sport</option>
         <option value="categorie2">movies</option>
         <option value="categorie3">news</option>


        </select>

<div class="article deactive categorie1">article 1 </div>
<div class="article deactive categorie1">article 2 </div>
<div class="article deactive categorie2">article 3 </div>
<div class="article deactive categorie2">article 4 </div>
<div class="article deactive categorie3">article 5 </div>
<div class="article deactive categorie3">article 6 </div>
```

Comment: Just curious to know, why you need Bootstrap source files here ?

Comment: I simply added for better visibility or better UI @DeepakYadav.

Comment: lol! If you see my code properly, h1 style is changed because of bootsrap only

Comment: he he he ! **LOL** ! and what happens if you remove it ?

Comment: I already have said you that, I added bootstrap for style like fonts or other things only @DeepakYadav. Are you mad or what?

Comment: now um sure, you are mad. For your kind information this was not mine issue. I have given solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$('#selectleft').change(function()
{
   var x = $('#select').val();
   $('.x').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: bro are u high xD check answers,ty tho